# M2.2.4 - Order comments in backend, make asc order instead of desc

Tags: magento2, sales-order, backend, magento2.2.4, order-comment

We have some extensions that attach comments to the order comments area of an order, however we also have the customer comment order as well, which we would like to make the primary comment on the order in the backend.

The customer order is always the first one attached, then the others get attached right after, so they end up being the 'latest' order comment, putting it at the top, but when syncing into our inventory system, it grabs the most recent comment which we don't particularly need, and would like it to grab the very first comment. Changing the order to descending will allow for this to happen we believe.

I assume this is possible, where is the order comments sort order determined?

Comment: I would say the problem is with the inventory sync and not magento. So changes need to be made there. How do you do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that would even even be an option or possibility, that's why I'm trying to see if the very customizable magento can just make this small change, if only I could find how it's done lol